# Google Calendar Api Intermittent 401

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a simple code that Logs into to Google to use the Google Calendar API and creates and event for the user. The code works fine but every so often I get a 401 - Login Required error from Google. If I open the developer console in the browser and try again it works... which is very odd

```
var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
var clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
var apiKey = 'API_KEY';

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth,1);
}

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeButton = $('#calendarAuth');
    var calendarFrame = $('#calendarFrame');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        authorizeButton.remove();
        calendarFrame.show();
        calendarFrame.attr('src', calendarFrame.attr('src')); //Hack to reload the iframe
    } else {
        authorizeButton.show();
        calendarFrame.hide();
    }
}

function Authorize() {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}


function GoogleScheduleFollowup(followup) {
    gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
            "calendarId": "primary",
            resource: {
                "summary": followup.title,
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": window.GetFullDateString(followup.date, followup.time)
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": window.GetFullDateString(followup.date, followup.time)
                }
            }
        });

        request.execute(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp);
    });
}
```

Everything seems to be well configured in the API Console, and I'm sure we haven't reached the quota (either total or requests per second). As an example today I have made 133 requests of which 36 failed with this error.

I have tried to call gapi.auth.authorize every 10 minutes to see if the problem was a session timeout, and as I read in another question I tried removing this line `gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);`, both without success

Comment: How often is this happening?  Could the access token have expired? the client library should be refreshing your access token as needed, its weird that its not doing that.  I don't think calling authorize  will help as the client lib should know it hasn't expired yet and not bother refreshing it.  (I think)

Comment: I have several users so it's hard to pinpoint how often it happens. For some it seems to happen very soon, others can go hours before it starts happening